# change text of clock display using gstreamer 0.10

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer

os : linux
gstreamer version : 0.10(this is requirement , so I cant migrate to 1.0)

Issue: change default text with grey to something more visible like black for clock display

Summary:
I am using gstreamer c code to stream video from webcam and at top of video it display time but unfortunately its in grey so its difficult to see it . Can someone please let me know how to make to black or to some other colour.
below is my snippet of code.

```
    source         = gst_element_factory_make( "v4l2src",          "source"         );
    g_object_set( G_OBJECT ( source ), "device", "/dev/video0", NULL );


    clockDisplay   = gst_element_factory_make( "clockoverlay",     "clock-time"     );
    capsFilter     = gst_element_factory_make( "capsfilter",       "camera_caps"    );
    conv           = gst_element_factory_make( "ffmpegcolorspace", "Colorconverter" );

    videoRate      = gst_element_factory_make( "videorate",        "videorate-element");
    capsFilterRate = gst_element_factory_make( "capsfilter",       "video-rate");
    videoEnc       = gst_element_factory_make( "ffenc_mpeg4",      "videoenc" );
    udpSink        = gst_element_factory_make( "udpsink",          "udpsink"  );
    g_object_set( G_OBJECT( udpSink ),
                  "host", hostAdd.c_str(), 
                  "port", PORT_NUM_REMOTE_FOR_STREAMING,
                  NULL
                  );

    // cap filter #1
    caps           = gst_caps_from_string( "video/x-raw-yuv,format=(fourcc)YUY2,width=320,height=240,framerate=10/1" );
    g_object_set ( capsFilter, "caps", caps, NULL );
    gst_caps_unref( caps );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the properties of clockoverlay with:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 clockoverlay
```

There should be properties related to the color of the text. In 1.0 it is named 'color'. Then just use g_object_set to set the color as an int in ARGB format. There is also an 'outline-color' to make it even more visible.

Comment: thansk mate , That really helped and also now i got an idea of how to change properties of other GstElements. Thanks